# No pubspec.yaml found afer creating example folder

Tags: flutter, dart

After creating an example folder to put my examples files on it, i was not able to run `flutter pub get` this is happen either on flutter project and dart package also, and when i get packages from *.yaml file or from command line, folder bellow is the console log where the root project is **idempierews_flutter**

> Running "flutter pub get" in idempierews_flutter...                 0.4s
>   /home/itbridge/workspaces/flutter/packages/idempierews_flutter/example: no pubspec.yaml found
>   exit code 1

Comment: work around, when i changed the name of the example folder to texample i was able to get packages, but this is not a solution since the name does not fit to package layout conventions

Comment: Hi did you found any solutiono of this? im having the same problem developing a flutter package!, im trying to create a example folder and have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Be sure be on the project directory and not on any sub-directory and then from your terminal run first `flutter clean` and then `fluter run`

hope this solves the problem.

Comment: did you try to add example folder and run flutter pub get before you answer, cause it didn't resolve the problem!